# RazorGenerator.MsBuild - Achieving harmony from Developer machine to Buildserver

Tags: razor, msbuild, resharper, codegen

We are currently using the RazorGenerator library to generate pre-compiled views for a project. Up until now we have been using the Visual Studio Extension to handle the generation, with these generated files also being committed to our repository.

This is causing bit of a pain point as we constantly have to resolve merge defects in a generated file. With that in mind I've set about to try and integrate the RazorGenerator.MsBuild target library into our build process so we can get away from storing the code-genned files in our repository.

So far I've disabled the VS Extension, and got the build target working as required however I've now lost intellisense and resharper support for the generated files as they are no longer part of the Solution.

I'm wondering if anyone else has come down this path before, Ideally what I'm trying to achieve is using the Build target to generate the cs files, removing the need to include these cs files in the repository, and still having Intellisense/Resharper coverage for the generated files.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved this problem by creating a an empty partial class for each of the cshtml templates which implements our own base class, which in-turn implements `RazorGenerator.Templating.RazorTemplateBase`.

By doing it this way we have access to all the publicly accessible properties and methods exposed on those classes which makes intellisense/resharper happy and at build time the templates .cs files are generated which do the heavy lifting for outputting the layout etc.